# Why does administrator login redirect to frontend on localhost?

Tags: joomla-2.5

I did an akeeba backup of a live Joomla 2.5.28 site where this issue doesn't exist. Used kickstart to install the backup on my localhost (xampp) and when I go to the administrator login page and enter my credentials, I'm being redirected to the frontend. Manually returning to administrator folder returns the login page. I am able to login on the frontend.

Things I've tried;

- Password reset via phpmyadmin (as I stated I can login on frontend)
- Disabled plugins that might be url redirect related. I'm not using JSecure. Plugins that I've disabled include sef, admintools,    sh404sef, and a few others which may be suspect.
- Removed the .htaccess files
- Set the live site url in configuration.php
- overrite all system files with a fresh J v2.5.28
- traceroute on frontend index returns null

I've spent hours and hours searching and have found no working solution. Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check to see if you've used Akeeba's admin tools to restrict the IP address that can login.

Comment: Have you tried restoring a backup *without* using Akeeba and doing it manually? Might be worth giving this a try too.

Comment: try removing `live site`, that's not needed - `public $live_site = '';`

Answer (score 1):

The things you have tried are correct and a good troubleshooting steps list for the issue you have, with 1 exception:

You mention in your question:

> Set the live site url in configuration.php

Actually this should be left empty - almost always (either online or localhost).

Another thing you have to make sure in the configuration file:
You should not have assigned any values to the `$cookie_` variables, otherwise it's likely you will not be able to login.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by admin tools url restriction or by ip.

If you go into the database and disable akeeba plugins you will be able to login.